# Copy files in ftp server Python

Tags: python, ftplib

I was able to copy files in the ftp server to a different location by writing the file to the webserver and then uploading it again.

Is there any way that I can write the file contents to memory without writing it to the harddisk and uploading them to the server. This is my code.

```
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'OpenTable','tempfiles')

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftphost')
ftp.login('username','password')
filenames = []
ftp.retrlines('NLST', filenames.append)
for filename in filenames:

    if filename[len(filename)-3:] == 'zip':

        ftp.cwd("/")
        filepath1 = os.path.join(filepath,filename)
        print filepath1
        r = open(filepath1,'w')

        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, r.write)
        ftp.cwd("/BackUp")
        r.close()
        r = open(filepath1,'r')

        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, r)
        r.close()
        os.remove(filepath1)
        print 'Successfully Backed up ', filename
ftp.quit()
```

I tried using the StringIO. It doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried with StringIO, and tell how it failed?